# How to convert text into bitmap in android?

Tags: android

How to convert text into bitmap in android? I am facing an issue where I need to convert text to bitmap so that I can create the mirror image of the text.

Answer (score 1):

this is how you get a bitmap from a view. (I assumed that with 'text' you were referring to textview

```
private static Bitmap get_view_image(View view) {
    int w = view.getWidth();
    int h = view.getHeight();
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable!=null)  {
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
    else {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
    view.draw(canvas);
    return bmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly mirror the bitmap (if you have one) using

```
BitmapDrawable flip(BitmapDrawable d)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.preScale(-1, 1);
    Bitmap src = d.getBitmap();
    Bitmap dst = Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), m, false);
    dst.setDensity(DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT);
    return new BitmapDrawable(dst);
}
```